# Balancing Redis queries and in-process memory?

Tags: performance, caching, architecture, redis

I am a software developer but wannabe architect new to the server scalability world.

In the context of multiple services working with the same data set, aiming to scale for redundancies and load balancing.

The question is: In a idealistic system, should services try to optimize their internal processing to reduce the amount of queries done to the remote server cache for better performance and less bandwidth at the cost of some local memory and code base or is it better to just go all-in and query the remote cache as the single transaction point every time any transaction need processing done on the data?

When I read about Redis and even general database usage online, the later seems to be the common option. Every nodes of the scaled application have no memory and read and write directly to the remote cache on every transactions.

But as a developer, I ask if this isn't a tremendous waste of resources? Whether you are designing at electronic chips level, at inter-thread, inter-process or inter-machine, I do believe it's the responsibility of each sub-system to do whatever it can to optimize its processing without depending on the external world if it can and hence reduce overall operation time.

I mean, if the same data is read over hundreds or time from the same service without changes (write), isn't it just more logical to keep a local cache and wait for notifications of changes (pub/sub) and only read only these changes to update the cache instead reading the bigger portion of data every time a transaction require it? On the other hand, I understand that this method implies that the same data will be duplicated at multiple place (more ram usage) and require some sort of expiration system not to keep the cache from filling up.

I know Redis is built to be fast. But however fast it is, in my opinion there's still a massive difference between reading directly from local memory versus querying an external service, transfer data over network, allocating memory, deserialize into proper objects and garbage collect it when you are finished with it. Anyone have benchmark numbers between in-process dictionaries query versus a Redis query on the localhost? Is it a negligible time in the bigger scheme of things or is it an important factor?

Now, I believe the real answer to my question until now is "it depends on your usage scenario", so let's elaborate:

Some of our services trigger actions on conditions of data change, others periodically crunch data, others periodically read new data from external network source and finally others are responsible to present data to users and let them trigger some actions and bring in new data. So it's a bit more complex than a single web pages deserving service. We already have a cache system codebase in most services, and we have a message broker system to notify data changes and trigger actions. Currently only one service of each type exist (not scaled). They transfer small volatile data over messages and bigger more persistent (changing less often) data over SQL. We are in process of moving pretty much all data to Redis to ease scalability and performances. Now some colleagues are having a heated discussion about whether we should abandon the cache system altogether and use Redis as the common global cache, or keep our notification/refresh system. We were wondering what the external world think about it. Thanks

(damn that's a lot of text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would favor utilizing in-process memory as much as possible. Any remote query introduces latency. You can use a hybrid approach and utilize in-process cache for speed (and it is MUCH faster) but put a significantly shorter TTL on it, and then once expired, reach further back to Redis.